# Who has IE6 users viewing their site?

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

I know the general advice is that its no longer necessary to support IE6, but I've also heard the best data is the analytics of actual users to your site. All of my sites are currently low traffic so I can't really use my data on this. Can anyone share their findings regarding IE6 and what types of sites (if any) are visited by IE6 and so should be supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the percentage of IE users for a website for a vacation city in the US. It gets approximately 50,000 visitors a month.

```
Msie 9.0  2.6 % 
Msie 8.0  42.6 %    
Msie 7.0  13.9 %    
Msie 6.0  2.6 %

Firefox   13.4 % (all versions)
Chrome    6.3 % (all versions)
Safari    16 % (all versions)
```

Answer (score 5):

Depends on your demographics.  Take these 2 sites I operate for example, both with HIGH traffic.

**Site 1** - blog regarding coding, PDO & databases.  Demographic - tech forward, early adopters.

IE use TOTAL - 8.7%.
ie6 use - negligible.

**Site 2** - retail site in a mature community with an average customer age of 46.

IE use TOTAL - 52%
ie6 use - 4.8%

**Another option** is to code for ie7+ and redirect all ie6 users to an "Update your ie version" page.
[redirect ie6 users](http://sonspring.com/journal/redirect-ie6)
[redirect / block ie6 users](http://twodayslate.wordpress.com/2007/09/09/blockredirect-ie6-users/)

Answer (score 1):

The most common users of IE6 are those where upgrades are a real headache - big corporate or public sector offices are the most common.

One of the reasons for this is that the intranet or some other internal web-based app only works in IE6. Consequently, everyone has to be upgraded simultaneously.

So if you're targeting big bluechip companies or public sector organisations, IE6 should be important to you.

Otherwise, get it working to a bare minimum, use cross-browser polyfills and provide a message in the FAQ about why your site doesn't look as amazing in IE6 as it does in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This month my highest traffic site received 1.35% visitors from IE 6.

This has been going down. The same period last year had 3.5% and I suspect the rate will continue as computers get replaced and upgraded.

In September last year I officially discontinued support for IE 6 and 7 on one of my sites and that impacted about 7% of visitors at the time. This let me give neat features to most of the remaining 93%. Millions of visitors later, not a single complaint :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've heard, it just worries me that W3Schools says there is about the same number of people on IE6 and Opera: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Answer (score 0):

Stats from Google Analytics for my blog. Traffic is mostly tech and Wordpress related. Over the past month I had 13k visits, 23% were IE and broken down by version:

8.0
    2,128   72.01%
7.0
    421     14.25%
9.0 288     9.75%
6.0
    118     3.99%

That translates to about 0.9% IE6 usage.

Answer (score 0):

Hobby related blog, 76,000 visits year to date.  IE6 makes up 2.26% of this.

Answer (score 0):

Some really good specific answers here which is great. Very interesting to see the differences according to site demographics.

Just out of interest. [StatCounter Global Stats](http://gs.statcounter.com/) are showing IE6 at 4.14% in April 2011 down from 10.13% in April 2010 so a significant downwards trend.

As Blowski stated, this is all very well unless you are supporting big blue chips or public sector where IE 6 is still in use. We are currently having to develop for the Ministry of justice and part of the contract is the system *has to work* on IE6.

Does anyone have any Paracetamol spare. I have a raging headache!

Answer (score 0):

We only have 10% visitors using IE, most popular is Firefox with 45% followed by Chrome with 31%.

Of our IE users only 5% are on IE6, which means it represents 0.5% of the total.

Our site is probably considered more tech savvy than most sites though.  Which makes my life a lot easier as the developer for sure!

Answer (score 0):

I write on HubPages about travel and my stats are:

- IE (all flavors) - 34.60%

  - IE 8 - 74.13%
  - IE 7 - 18.16%
  - IE 6 - 5.22%
  - IE 9 - 2.47%
  - IE 5.5 - 0.01%
  - IE 999.1 - 0.01% (what's 999.1)
- Firefox (all flavors) - 29.97%
- Chrome - 19.42%
- Safari - 12.39%
- Opera - 1.59%
- Opera Mini - 0.87%
- Mozilla Compatible Agent - 0.54%
- BlackBerry9700 - 0.08%
- Mozilla - 0.07%
- RockMelt - 0.07% (what's this?)

Answer (score 0):

It really would depend on your audience. If you're targeting big corporations or schools, etc. the IT staff may not have had the resources needed to upgrade yet. I recently was testing out a site designed as an educational site targeted for elementary school kids, and was able to do on-site testing at a local school. Sure enough, the browser they were using was IE6, and there were a number of errors that popped up with the design that I had to go back and adjust for that old browser.

Answer (score -1):

IE6 has too low of percentage to even count it.

Here are stats of browsers from a site that receives over 1 million unique hits a month.

```
* -IE8 - 29.2%
* -FF 3.6 - 16.3%
* +Chrome 10/11 - 12.9%
* -IE7 - 11.4%
* +Safari5 - 7.7%
* +FF4 - 6.6%
* None - 5.5% Traffic requested from browsers with no header 
* +IE9 - 3.8%
* Opera 11 - 0.4%
```

Comment: -1 What type of site? If it was "help-for-ie6-users.com" I am sure the proportion of IE6 would be significantly higher.